# Treating psTree object as a figure

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I created the following probability tree diagram using psTree then running XeLaTeX in texmaker.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\psset{treemode=R}

\begin{center}
\psTree{\Tcircle{16}} 
    \pstree{\Tcircle{11}\taput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    {{\Tcircle{12}}\taput{$\frac{1}{2}$}    {\Tcircle{13}}\tbput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
\pstree{\Tcircle{15}\tbput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    {\Tcircle{14}}\tbput{$1$}
\endpsTree
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I want to treat the tree diagram as a figure in my LaTeX document, but I'm stuck.

What I've been doing is taking a screenshot of the tree diagram in the preview box of texmaker, then inserting it into a LaTeX document by doing something like this

```
\begin{figure}[pngfile]
  \caption{Tree Diagram}
  \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pngfile}
\end{figure}
```

Could you recommend a better way?

Comment: you can just replace the `center` env in your original by  `\begin{figure}\caption{tree diagram}.. \end{figure}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It works! The solution was easier than I thought. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1:

Create the diagram.

```
% filename: diagram.tex

% compile it with the following sequence to get diagram.pdf
% latex diagram
% dvips diagram
% ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None diagram.ps


\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{treemode=R}

\begin{document}
\psTree{\Tcircle{16}} 
    \pstree{\Tcircle{11}\taput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    {{\Tcircle{12}}\taput{$\frac{1}{2}$}{\Tcircle{13}}\tbput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
\pstree{\Tcircle{15}\tbput{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    {\Tcircle{14}}\tbput{$1$}
\endpsTree
\end{document}
```

### Step 2:

Import the diagram from within the main document.

```
% filename: main.tex

% compile it with pdflatex thrice (probably more) to make  the cross-referencing work properly
% pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode main
% pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode main
% pdflatex main

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

In PSTricks we trust, how about you?
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics{diagram}
\caption{PSTricks is fun}
\label{fig:diagram}
\end{figure}

See Fig~\ref{fig:diagram} on page~\pageref{fig:diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I like this solution very much.

Comment: @MariaReyes: It is actually the recommended best practice approach. "Separation of concern" : Separating each diagram from the main document. :-) Don't forget to vote it up (optional).